# How to create Quiz app using Volley library

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am creating quiz app from volley library in android. where I get data in Array list from external website. now problem is that how to set data in `Textview` and `Buttons`. I created one `Textview`for show question, four `Buttions` for options, and Two more `Buttions` for go to next question and go to previous question. [here is image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1Na1.png)

I want that when i click one of the option button than his color will be blue and rest of button will be grey. when i click next button than load new question and all options button will be grey.
here is my main activity.java code. please help me in create quiz app.

```
package com.ravindra.excelrecycleview;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.android.volley.DefaultRetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.RetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private QuestionAdapter mQuestionAdatpter;
    private ArrayList<question> mquestion;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    ProgressDialog loading;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recylcer_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mquestion = new ArrayList<>();
    mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    parseJSON();
}
private void parseJSON(){
    loading =  ProgressDialog.show(this,"Loading","please wait",false,true);
 String url ="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw6eHqtKTxHoS9HPSdfTasY-iebLQXUgS3sHHiOpeuGxJfssBI/exec?action=getQuestions";
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("items");
                        for (int i =0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                            JSONObject items = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            String questions = items.getString("questions");
                            String optiona = items.getString("optiona");
                            String optionb = items.getString("optionb");
                            String optionc = items.getString("optionc");
                            String optiond = items.getString("optiond");
                            String correctans = items.getString("correctans");
                            String explain = items.getString("explain");

                            mquestion.add(new question(questions,optiona,optionb,optionc,optiond,correctans,explain));

                        }
                        mQuestionAdatpter = new QuestionAdapter(MainActivity.this,mquestion);
                        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mQuestionAdatpter);
                        loading.dismiss();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    } );
    mRequestQueue.add(request);
    int socketTimeOut = 50000;
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeOut, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);

    request.setRetryPolicy(policy);


}
}
```

Comment: I guess you have an adapter, just set click listener for button and on click listener button change it's color and also in the questions model add a field isSelected. 
[Here is a helping link](https://medium.com/@droidbyme/android-recyclerview-with-single-and-multiple-selection-5d50c0c4c739)  just mold it according to your need

Comment: I don't have any adapter for button and on click listener. i am beginner so please help me with code.

Comment: You can  create a `Recyclerview` for options as it could be dynamic not fixed to four options  and in adapter follow the link with checkbox visible , invisible change color of button instead, Please try and post your updated code so we could help you further.

Comment: can you provide me code for this.

Comment: sure let me create a similar scenario at my end.

Comment: can i provide all code